# Isolated ground on sub panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, breaker-box

Is it ok to use the brass rod grounding at a subpanel as long as the ground and the neutral bars are isolated at the sub panel from each other?

Answer (score 2):

A grounding electrode (ground rod) serves a totally different purpose than the equipment ground run with the feeder. One does not, and can not, take the place of or be used for, the other.

For a feeder run to a sub-panel for quite a few years now you MUST run a 4-wire feeder; two hots, neutral, ground.
If the panel is in a detached structure to the house then you must also install grounding electrode(s). There are several ways to accomplish this, but ground rods are the most common. Typically two ground rods are required.

Even with older codes that allowed a "3-wire" feeder (where the ground was omitted and the neutral served both purposes) a grounding electrode was still required.

Bottom line to remember for sub-panels: detached structure needs grounding electrodes, attached or within the same structure does not.

Comment: Thank you that is very good information to know .  my main disconnect panel 200 amps I have an a grounding rod and I have and equipment ground  running to a water line further I have the equipment ground bound to the neutral bar resolving back to the grounding rod basically the equipment ground and the neutral electrode the ground rod are band together. In the main disconnect panel is this good to have everything resolving back to the grounding rod basically?

Comment: From what I can surmise it all sounds right, but you have it backwards. In the main panel everything resloves back to the neutral bar, which is bonded to the panelboard via the neutral to ground bond. This bond is called the "main bonding jumper". This main bonding jumper in the main panel/disconnect only, is what creates the path for the equipment ground, which is the path for fault current to allow circuit breakers to trip and fuses to blow.

Comment: This topic is quite deep and cannot be adequately explained in a few message board posts, if you are interested you can search the web, there is a lot of good info out there.

Comment: that is very interesting. Thank you for that perspective on tripping the breakers. If I May digress, is it ok to have equipment ground tied to a water line in the sub panel? And we already know that the neutral and the equipment ground in the sub panel are isolated. Thanks for your time .

Comment: @SteveHowerton The water line should be *bonded* to the equipment grounding system, yes -- but it is not a *ground electrode* -- you'll want to drive a rod for that.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The water main can sometimes be used as a grounding electrode, if it meets certain criteria.

Comment: @Tester101, in fact a water main MUST be used as an electrode under certain conditions.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- interesting.  I personally wouldn't rely on it as a ground electrode as I don't know what material the pipe in the trench is made from -- having six inches of copper stuck in the ground before it turns into (insert plastic here) isn't helpful...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That's one of the criteria, that the pipe be metal and in the ground for 10' (I think it's 10').

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I'm not sure that's true?  Seems like NEC allows you to choose from a list of acceptable options.  The pipe has to be bonded, but I'm not sure it MUST be used as an electrode.

Comment: @Tester101 -- that sounds about right, but how do you know that about your specific pipe?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel If you're on municipal water, the utility should know. If not, you'd have to either verify it, or use an alternative grounding electrode.

Comment: @Tester101, they changed the wording in the code for the list of acceptable electrodes from "if available" to "if present". So if a water pipe is present an is metallic and is in contact with the soil for ten feet or more then it must be used as an electrode.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey What's the code section you're referring to, 250.50?

Comment: @Tester101, yes, the first sentence of 250.50. The change was in 2005 that removed the words "if available" and changed them to "that are present".

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I see, so all available grounding electrodes have to be bonded together.

Comment: @Tester101, Yes. This was the same change that requires footing rebar to be bonded. There were several cases where inspectors made guys break up concrete to bond the rebar since it was "present", although not "available".

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- yeah, my intent was "please do bond to the water pipe if it's made of metal, just don't rely on it as a sole ground electrode"